# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not working on UIWebview to stop html5 video

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i'm trying to stop a html5 video with the following statement for an UIWebview element

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.querySelector('video').pause();"];
```

but it don't works for me. I tried the javascript code with a onclick event and it works.

here the objective-c code

```
(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
// encode the string
NSString * result = [[[request URL]absoluteString]
                     stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// extract the path components from the result string
NSArray *pathElements = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[result pathComponents]];

// when click the a tag the video should stop 
if([pathElements[[pathElements count] -1] isEqualToString:@"tester"]){
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.querySelector('video').pause();"];
    }
}
```

here the html5 code

```
<video width="720px" height="396px" controls="controls" >
        <source src="Video.m4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<!-- a tag only for test purpose -->
<p><a href="/tester" target="_blank">TESTLINK</a></p>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called before the page loads, it is asking you IF it shouldStartLoadWithRequest

[UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)

> webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
>
> Sent before a web view begins loading a frame.

So you might need a Button and a toolbar, or some other way to trigger a method to execute the code AFTER the page has loaded, also you should make sure that "document.querySelector('video')" actually returns the video tag when called.

Comment: HI Emanuel, i think the function is the right place for this code because i have serveral html5 pages in a Scrollview and on the first page is he video. So when the user touch/sroll to the next page the video has to stop. You know? The Javascript code works when you call it within the html document with an onclick event maybe like       <button onclick="document.querySelector('video').pause();">test button </button>